# Why is it necessary to create a conda environment for Tensorflow during installation? Why can't we install Tensorflow through pip?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

When installing tensor on anaconda, the command to do it is;

```
$ conda create -n tensorflow
```

Why is it necessary to create a conda environment for Tensorflow? Why not simply use pip to install tensorflow like most other python packages?

I am using anaconda python 3.6

Comment: I have exactly the same question...I needed to create an environment to install Tensorflow with Conda. I still do not understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. It is not necessary to create conda environment for Tensorflow. Tensorflow can be installed through pip. This has been done and tested.